# React Native: glitch when dragging view

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to be able to drag and move a View using touch events. The render is glitchy, flickering. The app seem to be confused by the moving view itself. Responder values are glitchy only if i move it.

how can i prevent that?

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import {
  Animated,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
const CURSOR_SIDE_SIZE = 20;
const CURSOR_HALF_SIDE_SIZE = CURSOR_SIDE_SIZE / 2;
export default (props) => {
  const touch = useRef(
    new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 0, y: 0 })
  ).current;
  
  return (
    <View 
    onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}
    onResponderMove={(event) => {
      touch.setValue({
        x: event.nativeEvent.locationX,
        y: event.nativeEvent.locationY,
      });
    }}
    style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          left: Animated.subtract(touch.x, CURSOR_HALF_SIDE_SIZE),
          top: Animated.subtract(touch.y, CURSOR_HALF_SIDE_SIZE),
          height: CURSOR_SIDE_SIZE,
          width: CURSOR_SIDE_SIZE,
          borderRadius: CURSOR_HALF_SIDE_SIZE,
          backgroundColor: 'orange',
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: answer here https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder